# How to add Links in liferay

Tags: java, liferay

I am using Liferay 6.0.4 and I have a page which is available to all users including guests. The page is called "Information". The page has already been created.
Right now its an empty page.

I want to add these four links to that page on the left hand side:
1. Calender
2. Forums
3. Blogs
4. Docs
I have created that page with 30:70 layout so that I can place one Web Content showing these four url's on the left side and corresponding link content on the right side. The default content to show is the content of the link Calender.

I am not able to figure out how to achieve it as I am really new to Liferay. Please guide to me to the proper direction and if possible write some steps to follow...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want a menu on the left hand side that updates the right hand side.

For this, you should use the **Navigation Portlet** on the left hand side, and create 4 child pages "Calendar", "Forums", "Blogs" and "Docs". On each of these pages, just drop the appropriate portlet and you're set.